# Configuring Bazaar repository on Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bazaar

I already figured I can run the server by running (assuming repository is in /var/bzr):

```
bzr server --directory=/var/bzr
```

But now a couple of questions arises:

1. This doesn't solve a problem of starting bazaar automatically when server boots. I assume the best way would be to make a script in /etc/init.d that would run and stop bazaar server when appropriate, then put symlinks to it into /etc/rc.d/*. If you have an example of said script, please show it. Especially how to properly stop server (the very instance we started), starting is pretty obvious.
2. Security. I think the best approach would be to create a dedicated user (with a login, say, bzr), give that user permissions only to repository directory and run server as this user.
3. How to commit to this central repository? If I try to commit remotely, I get this message: "bzr: ERROR: Cannot lock LockDir(filtered-169532780:///StreetCleaner/.bzr/branch/lock): Transport operation not possible: readonly transport" Does this mean I can only commit/merge when logged via ssh? If so, do you have anything that can simplify the process?
4. Is there any way to add some kind of authentication to bazaar server?

I'm on Ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I would recommend using [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) to automatically start and stop the service on boot/shutdown
2. Agreed
3. By default the `bzr server` command gives a read-only server, you have to add the `--allow-writes` argument to enable writing.
4. Unfortunately `bzr server` has no authentication build-in. If you want authentication than I recommend using `bzr+ssh` or `bzr+https`. Here's a guide for using a webserver: http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/latest/en/user-guide/http_smart_server.html

Comment: Thanks for the help :) In the end, I went for ssh+bzr path, as it is a most simple one. I decided to create users specifically for repository access (like bzr_septi) and add the to a group for them to be able to manage repository.

Comment: Still, I checked out that Supervisor thingy and it looks very awesome :)